# gdb debug with more than one argument

Tags: gdb

I have a program that reads one image file, makes some changes on that image and then stores it.

The program runs like this:

```
./main file1.pgm file2.pgm
```

I'm using the `-g` flag so I can use GDB.

Now when I try to run GDB like this

```
# gdb main file1.pgm file2.pgm
```

i'm getting this error:

```
Excess command line arguments ignored. (file2.pgm)
```

How can I solve this?

My main needs those two arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how you pass arguments to a program to be run; it's taking `file1.pgm` as the name of a core file.

You want to use, *within* `gdb`,

```
gdb> :run file1.pgm file2.pgm
```

Answer (score 7):

From the command line like this:

```
gdb --args ./main file1.pgm file2.pgm
```

`run` at the GDB prompt *may* be more flexible if you are scripting extensively.

Answer (score 1):

Populate a .gdbinit with:

```
set args file1.pgm file2.pgm
```

then simply

```
gdb> run
```